# Show git commit history difference

Tags: git

What is the command to get a list of commits that are required to get from commit A to B and in reverse?
This would actually be the graph difference between the commit histories of two commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rev-list` can answer these three different, commonly-useful graph-difference questions:

- commits that are reachable from `B` but not from `A`:  `A..B` (or `B ^A` or `B --not A`)
- commits that are reachable from `A` but not from `B`:  `B..A` (or similar alternatives)
- commits on either `A` or `B` that are not on their common ancestors: `A...B` (doesn't matter which order you specify A and B here).

Consider this graph fragment:

```
-1-2-4-5-A
    \
     3-B
```

In this case there's no way to go forward from either `A` to `B` or vice versa, but you can get the last three commits along the top (4-5-A), or the two along the bottom (3-B), with `B..A` and `A..B` respectively.  You can get all five of these with `A...B`.  Using both `A..B` and `B..A` you can figure out what to remove from A (A itself, then 5, then 4) and then add (3 and `B` itself), to get "from A to B".

Commits are, as the documentation says, listed "in reverse chronological order by default", but this is also controllable.  You probably want `--topo-order` and sometimes `--reverse`.

However, in the presence of complex topology, a simple sequence like the above ("remove this, add that") is not sufficient.  For instance:

```
...-x-o-o-o-o-o-B
     \   /   /
      A-o-o-o
```

All of the `o` nodes may be important to get "from `A` to `B`", but now, no purely linear traversal (commit X before commit Y, then commit Z) can reconstruct the full graph: you need more information (e.g., listing the parents associated with each commit).  `git rev-list` can do all of this; read and study the man page examples closely.